# Restore navigationBar background image after setting it to [UIImage new]

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I needed a completely transparent navigation bar for the mapView so I did this:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setShadowImage:[UIImage new]];
```

That returns the desired effect, as seen here:

[image]

Now I have a problem when I go to any other because my navigationBar remains transparent:

[image]

How do I restore default settings of the navigationBar's backgroundImage and shadowImage?

Comment: add navigationbar image in viewWillDisappear method.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Set **nil** for image of navigation Controller on `viewWillDisappear` on map view

Set this two method in your mapview

**MapView**.m

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setShadowImage:[UIImage new]];
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:nil forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setShadowImage:nil];
}
```

Comment: viewWillDisappear is the point! I used viewDidDisappear, it is WRONG! Hope that can save other's time.

Comment: Does anyone experience the navigation bar turning black for a second in this transition?

Comment: It doesn't work together with large titles in iOS 11 - hopefully a bug that will be fixed. `[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:nil forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault]` doesn't restore the status bar.

Comment: This works for Swift 4 as well: `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(nil, for: UIBarMetrics.default)`

Comment: @JeevanThandi yes I do too. Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @turingtested Did you find a solution for Large title nav bar?

Answer (score 7):

**For Swift 3**:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
  super.viewWillAppear(animated)

  self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
  self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
  super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

  self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(nil, for: UIBarMetrics.default)
  self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

by the way, you get get the original background image by using function

```
UIImageView *imageView = [self.navigationController.navigationBar
backgroundImageForBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

and store the image somewhere, then you use

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:imageView 
forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

to set it back,but most time, set to nil will solve your problem.